# Create index for boolean columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, indexing

I have table that has 5 boolean columns.

```
on_stock | paid | received_payment | on_the_way | received
```

How to create an index for this table? Should I do it? I want to optimize a query like this:

```
SELECT "order".* FROM "order" INNER JOIN "seller_users" ON "order"."seller_foreign_id" = "seller_users"."google_id" 
WHERE(((("order"."on_stock" <> true AND "order"."on_the_way" <> true ) AND "order"."paid" <> true ) AND "order"."received_payment" <> true ) AND "order"."received" <> true ) AND ("seller_users"."google_id" = 'lala@gmail.com' ) 
ORDER BY "order"."updated_at" DESC ;
```

When I try add this index - nothing happens. This index is not used.

```
 add_index :order, [:on_stock, :on_the_way, :paid, :received_payment, :received], :name => "state_index"
```

If I add separate `index` for each columns - nothing happens too.

`EXPLAIN ANALYZE` output:
http://explain.depesz.com/s/FS2

Comment: You ll have to create separate `index` for every column.

Comment: @usmanali, It did not change anything.

Comment: Please could you [edit] in that EXPLAIN ANALYZE output as text. Or perhaps paste it into http://explain.depesz.com

Comment: @IMSoP,  done. I add link to explain.depesz.com

Comment: @usmanali Er, why? A partial index should be better for this use case, assuming they're always looking for `<> true` for each col. Otherwise a multi-col index is likely the right choice.

Comment: @ViT-Vetal- If for testing you `SET enable_seqscan = off` what plan do you get then? Also please show `\dt order` from `psql`

Comment: @CraigRinger, this is example. Possible not only 'true'

Comment: @CraigRinger, after  `enable_seqscan = off` postgres start using my index, but  gain is minimum:)

Comment: gain is minimum, since boolean index has low cardinality... unless you use it to "cluster" other column,based on the current boolean

Comment: Yup, and that's why PostgreSQL is choosing a seqscan. Indexes aren't magical go-faster juice, and you're seeing that here. A selection of partial indexes for high-selectivity subgroups might be more useful...

Answer (score 1):

Your table has a total of 8 rows, an index is not needed in this case. It is way faster to test each of this 8 rows against the `where` clause than to use an index here.